# Where is the second Python version installed?

Tags: python, cpanel, zope

I have a cpanel server with python 2.6.6 by default.

```
root@vps [~]# python --version
Python 2.6.6
root@vps [~]#
```

However, I also have Zope 2.9.5 installed which is running on an earlier version of Python. This is the info from the Zope admin page:

```
Zope Version
(Zope 2.9.5-final, python 2.4.3, linux2)
Python Version
2.4.3 (#1, Jul 1 2014, 04:19:44) [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)]
System Platform
linux2
SOFTWARE_HOME
/opt/Zope-2.9/lib/python
ZOPE_HOME
/opt/Zope-2.9
INSTANCE_HOME
/usr/local/zope_new_instance
CLIENT_HOME
/usr/local/zope_new_instance/var
Network Services
ZServer.HTTPServer.zhttp_server (Port: 8080)
Process Id
8781 (140167694149376)
Running For
59 days 4 hours 5 min 4 sec
```

I am trying to setup a new cpanel server with EXACTLY the same setup regarding Zope and Python. I do have the source for both Zope 2.9.5 as well as the source for Python 2.4.3. I am not sure where to install Python 2.4.3 though. Is there a command that will show me other python locations? **which python** shows me the default Python location.

Comment: I think the whereis-command could work. Could you try whereis python2.4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know Zope, but it looks like you're in Unix, so if you installed Python through apt, dnf, etc...:

- The symbolic link to Python is usually installed in `/usr/bin`. If you search by "python" in that folder you should find all the python available for you.
- If you are looking for the headers in `/usr/include` you should have a folder for each version of Python installed.

#### And you say: "I am not sure where to install Python 2.4.3 though".

If you're installing Python from source it will be installed in your local folder: `/usr/local/bin` (for symbolic link) and `/usr/local/include` for headers. Also, make sure to enable symbolic links when compiling. If I'm not wrong in the `./configure` step, you can use `./configure --enable-shared` to make sure that when you compile the source code it will installs you a symbolic link for that version in you `/usr/local/bin`